# How to debug a VB file that's supposed to perform SQL Server operations?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have a VB script that is part of an Access App that interfaces with a SQL Server database. I know what it's supposed to do, but I don't really understand VB (I'm more of a C-like language guy).

Here is the function, from what I can tell:

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    On Error GoTo btnOK_Click_Err

    Dim result
    Dim sql As String
    Dim mc As Integer   '* metercount
    Dim mca As Integer  '* meter accumulator
    Dim PostWhat As Integer
    Dim CurPd As Integer, CurYr As Integer, NumSumHist As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim conPost As Connection
    Dim sParam As String, userId As String, WrkStnId As String
    ReDim MsgLog(10) As String
    Dim qn As Integer
    Dim adocom As ADODB.Command
    Dim gCurrencyId As String
    Dim gLocId As String
    
    
    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    'disable button to prevent multiple executions
    Me!HaveYou.SetFocus
    Me!BtnOk.Enabled = False
    
    
    

    If Not Preprocessing() Then
        DoCmd.Hourglass False
        GoTo btnOK_Click_Exit
    End If
    
    
    
    
    Set adocom = New ADODB.Command
    With adocom
        .ActiveConnection = GetADOConnection()
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "dbo.qryCfCorrespndMerge"
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        .Parameters.Refresh
        '  If Not gDevYn Then Application.Run "StartServerStatus", "EDI Create SO Transaction ", 1000
        .Execute , , adAsyncExecute
        Do While .State = adStateExecuting
            DoEvents
        Loop
        'If Not gDevYn Then Application.Run "StopServerStatus", "EDI Create SO Transaction "
     
        If .Parameters(0) <> 0 Then
            'Post Failed
            Set adocom = Nothing
            Call GenGetMsg("XXGenOpFailRef", Me.Caption & "|" & .Parameters(0), " ")
            Call MsgBox("Correspondents Merge Failed", gMsgType, gMsgTitle)
            GoTo btnOK_Click_Exit
        End If
    End With
    Set adocom = Nothing
   
   
Finish_Post:
    On Error GoTo btnOK_Click_Err
   
    
    Lock_Cleanup
    
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    'result = GenGetMsg("ArPostTransComplete", " ", " ")
    result = MsgBox("Correspondents merge  successfully finished !", , gMsgTitle)
    DoEvents
    
   
    '* Open Report Form
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCfCorrMergeRpt"
    DoEvents

    

btnOK_Click_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    'ensure that everything gets shut down/unlocked/reset/etc.
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    
    'reenable buttons
    Me!BtnOk.Enabled = True
    Me!BtnOk.SetFocus
    Exit Sub


btnOK_Click_Err:
    Select Case Err
        Case Else
            gErrMod = Me.Name
            gErrProc = "BtnOk_Click"
            gErrDesc = Error$
            gErrCloseForm = Me.Name
            gErrResult = GenErr(adocom.ActiveConnection)
    End Select
    Resume btnOK_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

What's supposed to happen is the user clicks the print button and the app gathers all the data that is needed to print from the SQL Server database, however, it either goes nowhere, does nothing, or throws an error stating there is nothing to print. Aside from the potential for this to be a database procedure issue, What is this code doing? Is there any pull from a DB somewhere?

### Update:

After some analysis it's been determined that the issue is stemming from the SP on the SQL Database, the SP is as follows: (commented out code has been removed for brevity)

```
ALTER           proc [dbo].[qryCfCorrespndMerge]
as
declare @i int
declare @x int
declare @j int
declare @k int
declare @kk int
declare @InmateId varchar (10) 
declare @Gender char (1) 
declare @Language varchar (2)
declare @Region varchar(2)
set nocount on

create table #tmpOutsider
 (
    id int identity(1,1) not null  primary key,
    PersonId varchar (10) NOT NULL ,
    Gender char (1) NULL ,
    Language varchar (2) NULL ,
    NumAvailCont int null default 0,
    AreaRegion varchar (2) NULL,
    LastUpdated datetime ,
    MergeCount int default(0)
    
    
) 
create table #tmpInmate
 (
    id int identity(1,1) not null  primary key,
    PersonId varchar (10) NOT NULL ,
    Gender char (1) NULL ,
    Language varchar (2) NULL ,
    NumAvailCont int null default 0,
    AreaRegion varchar (2) NULL, 
    LastUpdated datetime,
    MergeCount int default(0)   
    
) 
begin tran
    set @i=0
    
    -- Outsiders (insert list of outsides who still write to fewer inmates than requested)
    insert into  #tmpOutsider(PersonId,Gender ,Language  ,NumAvailCont,AreaRegion,LastUpdated,MergeCount)
    
    select  p.PersonId,Gender ,Language ,(MaxContactNum -isnull(c.ContactNum,0)) as availCont ,AreaRegion ,ISNULL(c.LastUpdateDate,p.DateCreated),isnull(ContactNum,0)
    
    from  dbo.tblCfPerson p left outer join 
        (select CorrespId,count(CorrespId)ContactNum , Max(LastUpdateDate) LastUpdateDate 
        from dbo.tblCfContacts 
            group by CorrespId) c -- number of inmates already linked
        on p.personid=c.CorrespId
        where Type='O' and p.MaxContactNum>isnull(c.ContactNum,0)
    order by isnull(c.ContactNum,0) ,ISNULL(c.LastUpdateDate,p.DateCreated) -- use last merged date if null use date added

    -- if no outsiders than return
    select @i=count(*) from #tmpOutsider
    if  @i=0
        begin
        return 10 -- no outsiders
    end

    

        -- INMATES (insert list of insiders who still write to fewer outsiders than requested
    insert into  #tmpInmate(PersonId,Gender ,Language ,NumAvailCont,AreaRegion,LastUpdated,MergeCount)
    select p.PersonId,Gender ,Language  ,(MaxContactNum -isnull(c.ContactNum,0)) as availCont ,AreaRegion,ISNULL(c.LastUpdateDate,p.DateCreated),isnull(c.ContactNum,0) 
    from  dbo.tblCfPerson p left outer join 
        (select InmateId,count(InmateId) as ContactNum ,Max(LastUpdateDate) LastUpdateDate from dbo.tblCfContacts group by InmateId) c
    on p.personid=c.InmateId
    where Type='I' and p.MaxContactNum>isnull(c.ContactNum,0)
    order by isnull(c.ContactNum,0),isnull(c.LastUpdateDate,p.DateCreated)

    -- if no insiders than return
    select @i=0
    select @i=count(*) from #tmpInmate
    if  @i=0
        begin
        return 20 -- no inmates
    end


    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmpInmate) > 0
            BEGIN
        SELECT @I=0
            SELECT @I=(SELECT TOP 1 [ID] FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT [ID] FROM #tmpInmate ORDER BY MergeCount, LastUpdated) x)
        
        SELECT @gender=gender,@language=language,@region=arearegion,@InmateId=personid
        FROM #tmpInmate where [ID]=@i    
        SELECT @I=ISNULL(@I,0)      

            SELECT @j=0         
        SELECT @j=(SELECT TOP 1 [ID] FROM   
              (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT [ID] FROM #tmpOutsider t
               WHERE t.gender=@gender
               and t.language=@language
               and t.arearegion <> @region
               and t.personid not in (select distinct CorrespId from tblCfContacts where inmateid=@inmateid)        
               ORDER BY t.MergeCount,t.LastUpdated) x)

                SELECT @j=ISNULL(@J,0)  
        
        IF @j<> 0 
            BEGIN
             INSERT into dbo.tblCfContacts(InmateId,CorrespId,LastUpdateDate,Lang)
             select @inmateid,t.personid,getDate(),@language
             from #tmpoutsider t where id=@j            
              
             UPDATE #tmpInmate SET NumAvailCont=NumAvailCont-1, MergeCount=MergeCount+1,LastUpdated=GetDate() WHERE [ID]=@I
             UPDATE #tmpOutsider SET NumAvailCont=NumAvailCont-1,MergeCount=MergeCount+1, LastUpdated=GetDate() WHERE [ID]=@J           

                 DELETE #tmpInmate WHERE NumAvailCont=0
             DELETE #tmpOutsider WHERE NumAvailCont=0

            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
              DELETE FROM #tmpInmate WHERE [Id]=@I     
            END             
        
            
        END 

commit tran
return 0
```

Is there anything in this SQL script that could potentially cause problems? What kind of parameters is this expecting? I know it's setting two temporary tables, then running some calculations. (I've never debugged someone else's SQL before either. Any resources for that?

Comment: Thats not VB.NET and not even VB6 - it is Access-VBA

Comment: oh gah..... sorry editing now.

Comment: Yes, it runs a stored procedure in the database. `.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "dbo.qryCfCorrespndMerge"`. If 0 is not returned (0 is success for the sproc) then throw some errors. If successful then open the report form. Most of the other code changes UI elements to show the status or prevent the user from running the procedure multiple times or to reset the buttons after it runs. Difficult to troubleshoot what's going on in the sproc without the code.

Comment: I would create a new question for your stored procedure issue. 1) This question has answers to the original question so most likely no one is going to see your addon, 2) each question on SO should be a single question anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing you need to debug likely is the stored procedure.

These lines:

```
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.CommandText = "dbo.qryCfCorrespndMerge"
```

Specify that you're running a stored procedure, and which one it is.

Then this section:

```
If .Parameters(0) <> 0 Then
'Post Failed
    Set adocom = Nothing
    Call GenGetMsg("XXGenOpFailRef", Me.Caption & "|" & .Parameters(0), " ")
    Call MsgBox("Correspondents Merge Failed", gMsgType, gMsgTitle)
    GoTo btnOK_Click_Exit
End If
```

Checks an output parameter, and displays an error if it fails.

All the more relevant code probably is inside that stored procedure. The code you shared is pretty much only calling it, waiting, and then displaying an error if it didn't run correctly.

There are a lot of unused variables, commented out function calls, and other junk in there. You could try something like [RubberDuckVBA](http://rubberduckvba.com/) (open source, not affiliated) to refactor your code

Comment: Yeah I figured the VB wasn't doing the heavy lifting, I have access to get the SP but I'm a little fuzzy on debugging and grokking the code. I'm an amateur DB Admin only so I know how to query, but logic in SQL isn't my strong suit...... I'm going to modify the question tomorrow when I'm back in the office.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt at making sense of this thing. Basically many of the errors are being caught and then either ignored or lost inside of variables that are never used. It's a hot mess of spaghetti.

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    On Error GoTo btnOK_Click_Err

    'Declare a bunch of variables
    Dim result
    Dim sql As String
    Dim mc As Integer   '* metercount
    Dim mca As Integer  '* meter accumulator
    Dim PostWhat As Integer
    Dim CurPd As Integer, CurYr As Integer, NumSumHist As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim conPost As Connection
    Dim sParam As String, userId As String, WrkStnId As String

    'Not sure we why we are redim'ing an undim'd array...?
    ReDim MsgLog(10) As String
    Dim qn As Integer
    Dim adocom As ADODB.Command
    Dim gCurrencyId As String
    Dim gLocId As String


    'make an hourglass?
    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    'disable button to prevent multiple executions
    Me!HaveYou.SetFocus
    Me!BtnOk.Enabled = False



    'Call the "Preprocessing()" function and get a boolean back
    If Not Preprocessing() Then
        DoCmd.Hourglass False
        GoTo btnOK_Click_Exit
    End If



    'Here's the stuff you care about
    'Make a new ADO command. ADO is the library we use to interact
    'with databases in VBA.
    Set adocom = New ADODB.Command
    With adocom

        'Using the adocom command obect
        'Open a connection using the GetADOConnection() function (elsewhere in the vba I presume)
        .ActiveConnection = GetADOConnection()
        'Tell the command we will be running a proc on sql server
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

        'This is the procedure we will be running
        .CommandText = "dbo.qryCfCorrespndMerge"

        'Don't timeout ever.
        .CommandTimeout = 0

        'Refresh the params... not sure here
        .Parameters.Refresh

        'Execute the command 
        .Execute , , adAsyncExecute

        'Wait for it to finish. Not sure why you would call the proc
        '   in async mode and then wait for it to finish... whatevs
        Do While .State = adStateExecuting
            DoEvents
        Loop

        'Check the result and if the first parameter is anything besides 0 then
        ' something bad happened so raise a message box and call whatever
        ' that GenGetMsg is (I assume another function/subroutine that isn'that
        ' shared with this code dump)
        If .Parameters(0) <> 0 Then
            'Post Failed
            Set adocom = Nothing
            Call GenGetMsg("XXGenOpFailRef", Me.Caption & "|" & .Parameters(0), " ")
            Call MsgBox("Correspondents Merge Failed", gMsgType, gMsgTitle)
            GoTo btnOK_Click_Exit
        End If


    End With

    'Turn off the db connection
    Set adocom = Nothing


Finish_Post:

    'If there is an error on the next block of code then
    ' then go to the label called "btnOK_Click_Err"
    On Error GoTo btnOK_Click_Err

    'Call subroutine Lock_Cleanup which isn't shared in this
    '    code dump
    Lock_Cleanup

    'Turn off the hourglass
    DoCmd.Hourglass False

    'Set the variable called "result" to whatever this message box is returning...
    ' which makes no sense. The "result = " part can be removed probably
    result = MsgBox("Correspondents merge  successfully finished !", , gMsgTitle)
    DoEvents


    '* Open Report Form
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCfCorrMergeRpt"
    DoEvents



btnOK_Click_Exit:

    'If there is an error in the next block of code
    '   then continue on as if nothing bad happened
    '   OP... this is a bad idea. Literally if your
    '   app throws an error you will never know
    '   which might be part of the problem?
    '   remove this line and see if it throws an error
    On Error Resume Next
    'ensure that everything gets shut down/unlocked/reset/etc.
    DoCmd.Hourglass False

    'reenable buttons
    Me!BtnOk.Enabled = True
    Me!BtnOk.SetFocus

    'End this routine
    Exit Sub


btnOK_Click_Err:

    'You are only here because there was an error
    '   thrown after the Finish_Post label above
    Select Case Err
        'Not sure what this case statement is doing
        'But.. assuming ELSE then collect the error
        'into a bunch of variables.
        Case Else
            gErrMod = Me.Name
            gErrProc = "BtnOk_Click"
            gErrDesc = Error$
            gErrCloseForm = Me.Name
            gErrResult = GenErr(adocom.ActiveConnection)
    End Select

    'And go back up to this btnOK_Click_Exit
    ' label. But.. then we don't do anything
    ' with the variables we just collected
    ' so the error is lost on Exit Sub up in that label
    ' Perhaps a line like:
    ' msgbox "Error: " & gErrMod & "; Description: " & gerrDesc
    ' would be illuminating here....
    Resume btnOK_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: yeah, this is not my own code. this is a custom app from a vendor, and I don't trust their skills. They're developing in Access FGS....

Comment: To debug, I would just comment out the on "On Error" lines and let it fly. I would imagine the database is tossing an error that isn't being sent back in the parameter(0) of the command return, but is like "That object doesn't exist" or "Your credentials are wrong" and it's being lost in all the poor attempts at error handling that are in here.

Comment: Also, if this is vendor supplied code, you might want to consider deleting the question since they may claim it as copyrighted and cause a legal issue depending on how much of a pain in the ass they are.

Comment: Good Point. I'm the sole dev, so if it's alright, I'll keep it up until I get what I need to resolve the issue..... There is no longer a relationship with that vendor, and the org I work for owns the code, from my understanding. (We were the reason they wrote it, poorly....)

Comment: yeah, doesn't look like the SQL is going through. working with the SP, and it's failing with looking at the source table.

Comment: That's good news. At least it's not the VBA that is failing :)